# Why do my nested for loops in assembly result in an infinite loop

Tags: c++, visual-c++, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

My program is written in C++ with some x86 assembly language being embedded into it. I have 2 nested for-loops in assembly language that I must go through. However, however when I compile my program, I get an infinite loop. The equivalent program in C++ would look something like this:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a[4] = {3,6,4,7};

    for(int k = 0 ; k < 4;k++)
    {
        for(int l = 0 ; l < a[k];l++)
        {
            cout<<'*';
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

 /*

  *** 
  ******
  ****
  *******
  Press any key to continue . . .
  */
```

This is the same thing, but done with assembly mixed in.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void output(); //function for making an '*'
void makeSpace(); //function for making a space

int main()
{
    int a[4]={3,6,4,7};

    int counter = 0; //counter that will be used for first forloop
    int counter2 = 0; // counter to be used for second forloop

_asm{

    mov ebx,0 // this is to move from element 0,1,2,3,4, through the array
    mov ecx,0 // ecx will get the data from the array, only to be used as a
              // counter in forloop2 though.

     for1:

    cmp counter,4 //begins for firloop

    je starts 
    mov ecx,[a+ebx] // move the 0th element from array to ecx
    add ebx,4// ebx = ebx+4, I'm doing this to advance the array position (int)
    inc counter// increment counter by one

      for2:
    cmp counter2,ecx //begin forloop2, 
    je starts2
    call output
    inc counter2 //increment counter2 by one

    jmp for2 
      starts2:

    call makeSpace
    jmp for1
      starts:
}

    return 0;
}

void output()
{
    cout<<'*';
    }

void makeSpace()
{
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Why does this result in an infinite loop?

Comment: Two things (1) this is not a forum, there is no need to introduce yourself or greet us; (2) what exactly is your question?

Comment: Please add an actually informative title about what you're going to ask. What you currently have is not a title. And please properly format and indent your code.

Comment: Did you try building the c++ version and examining the assembly produced by your compiler?

Comment: @mah, no, but how can I go about doing that? I'm using a visual studio c++ compiler(2010)

Comment: If you debug your program in visual studio, you can run to an arbitrary breakpoint (to be conveniently around the code you want to inspect), and select Debug->Windows->Dissassembly. This will show you the assembly code in relation to its C/C++ code.

Comment: `eax`, `ecx`, `edx` are not preserved across function calls. After `call output` and `call makeSpace`, the values of these registers are undetermined.

Comment: I just tried accessing the assembly code by going to(while debugging) debug-> windows, but I see no dissemmbly option. I also placed 2 break points, one at the beginning, and one at the end. am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @Dcoder, you're right, so how can I go about fixing that? I know that I can use ebx, but ebx is reserved for my array. Should I replace ecx with a variable such as int element = 0;  ?

Comment: @VishalGupta: can you not save them to the stack before making a function call?

Comment: In this limited case, you can use another register instead of `ecx`, such as `esi` or `edi`. After you take care of that, look carefully at your inner loop, specifically at its initializer.

Comment: This can and must be debugged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two things you need to fix:

- When you call `output()` only the following registers are guaranteed to not be trashed:

  - `edi`, `esi`, `ebx`, and `ebp`

  In particular, you're using `ecx`, which the function is permitted to trash.
- You never reset `counter2` to 0, so the inner loop isn't equivalent to your C code.

Comment: Thanks, you solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer here is that you never preserve your registers prior to calling the functions `Output` and `MakeSpace`.  The standard function header doesn't guarantee anything about the `ecx` or `ebx` registers used in your `asm` code.